# How do I copy a folder, with subfolders & items, from the scripts location?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I'm trying to create a script that copies a folder, with subfolders, from the source-directory of the script to `C:\Tools`.

The folder is created fine, but no files are copied over and I get no error messages.

What am I doing wrong?

Code snippet below (PowerShell v2.0):

```
$from = Split-Path -Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition -Parent
$to =  C:\Tools\
New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path C:\Tools
New-Item -Force $to
Copy-Item "$from\Tools" $to -Recurse
```

Comment: I'd recommend upgrading your PowerShell version as MS stopped supporting v2 at the end of last year. I'd recommend at minimum v4 as a lot of useful functionality was included then.

Comment: Use `robocopy` rather than trying to script it.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
New-Item -ItemType directory -Path "C:\Tools" -Force | Out-Null

Copy-Item -Path "$(Split-Path -Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition -Parent)\Tools\*" `
          -Destination "C:\Tools\" `
          -Recurse
```

This is assuming a folder structure like this:

```
Root
  |
  |- CopyScript.ps1
  |- Tools
       |- File1.txt
       |- File2.txt
       ...
       |- SubFolder1
       |- Subfolder2
       ...
```

The snippet above will create the following:

```
C:\tools
   |- File1.txt
   |- File2.txt
   ...
   |- SubFolder1
   |- Subfolder2
   ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The examples in the documentation are always worth a look, for [Copy-Item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/copy-item) - example 3 is the same as you want to do:

> Example 3: Copy the contents of a directory to another directory and
>   create the destination directory if it does not exist
>
> `PS C:\> Copy-Item C:\Logfiles -Destination C:\Drawings\Logs -Recurse`
>
> This command copies the contents of the C:\Logfiles directory to the
>   C:\Drawings\Logs directory. It creates the \Logs subdirectory if it
>   does not already exist.

As `Copy-Item` will create the destination folder for you, you don't need to use `New-Item` first:

```
$from = Split-Path -Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition -Parent
$to =  "C:\Tools"

Copy-Item "$from\Tools" -Destination $to -Recurse
```